# Business Entity in Rails? Or How to separate that from models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `User` Model and it has a method like `checkAge`. Now I don't want this in the `User` model. I want `User` model to be clean. So where should I put the `checkAge` method.

Comment: it depends on where is you want to use it. so show with examples usage the method

Answer (score 2):

In our past project, we store business logical codes into the app/services folder（layer). Every business module define a pure ruby class. And controller call this service object to handle this stuff.

Comment: I also did the same. Put the module in app/services
And I `include UserBusinessEntity` in User Model. Now Its gives  `uninitialized constant User::UserBusinessEntity` error.

Answer (score 0):

Its totally depends on you, you can make separate classes and put code based on your requirement in those classes, Like @john mentioned you can add those classed in services, or you can add these classes in any sub folder in models

one other solution to just check age  then you should use a [decorator](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) if you need to show this on views

Answer (score 0):

You could put `checkAge` method in the `application_helper.rb` file in the helpers folder